# Sudden windows shut down during programming with Borland C++ followed by a blue screen!

Tags: c++, windows

This problem has happened to me twice.Both times during programming with Borland C++.when i wanted to run the simple code bellow:(completely what I wrote)

```
int n, total=0, counter=1,average;

while ( n )
{
   cin >> n;
   total = total + n;
   average = total / counter;
   counter++;
   cout <<average<<endl;
}
```

Comment: It's hard to say anything useful about the code as it is. What type is `n`? (Depending on that, the code might be able to produce an endless loop.) What's the initial value of `counter`? (It might cause a division by zero.) What about the other variables? Post compilable code.

Comment: Oh, and pleas don't yell at us!!!!!!!!

Comment: Belongs on Super User (if you were asking how to prevent your driver you are writing causing a BSOD it would belong here).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BSOD is almost always a hardware or driver issue. It could be that a particular sequence of program operations is exercising something that is failing.

Best thing to do is look at the memory dump in MS' analyzer to see if that points to a specific software item.